# OpenBankingProject, for api call `create custom view`. How to grant the `cancreatecustomview` permission

Tags: rest, open-banking

I am using the [Open Bank Project API Sandbox](https://apisandbox.openbankproject.com/). My issue is when performing the api call [Create a custom view on bank account](https://apiexplorersandbox.openbankproject.com/?version=OBPv5.1.0&operation_id=OBPv3_0_0-createViewForBankAccount&currentTag=View-Custom&locale=en_GB#OBPv3_0_0-createViewForBankAccount)

I am getting

`{code: 400, message: OBP-20022: View does not permit the access. You need the cancreatecustomview permission on any your views}`

Context:
After using a consumer app user-id to obtain a direct login token, I then sequentially and  successfully perform the following api calls;
`create a second bank user`, `create a customer`, `create a user-customer-link` for the second-user, `create an account` with second-user-id everything is good.

At this point I need to create a custom view for the account following the [steps here](https://apiexplorersandbox.openbankproject.com/glossary?locale=en_GB#Scenario-2%3A-Create-a-Public-Account).
Following these steps I receive the status 400 OBP-20022 above.

I have copied the full trace below.

From the trace it appears to be a permissions issue however when I try to add the  `cancreatecustomview` role the api reports that it does not exist.

api request and response truncated for readability

request url `https://obplite/obp/v5.1.0/banks/wl.1.uk/accounts/{USER_ID}/views`

the json body is the custom view, here I have shortened then long list of view permissions with .....

```
{"name":"_test","description":"This view is for family","metadata_view":"_test","is_public":true,"which_alias_to_use":"family","hide_metadata_if_alias_used":false,"allowed_actions":["can_see_transaction_this_bank_account", .....    "can_see_transaction_other_bank_account", "can_create_standing_order"]}
```

response `{code: 400, message: OBP-20022: View does not permit the access. You need the cancreatecustomview permission on any your views}`

interpreting the response as a direction to grant the role `cancreatecustomview`

request url `https://obplite/obp/v5.1.0/users/db40238c-8109-41ff-a605-9559291a4f4b/entitlements`

request body  `{"role_name":"CanCreateCustomView","bank_id":"wl.1.uk"}`

response include a long list of Roles shortened for readability

```
 {code: 400, message: OBP-10007: Incorrect Role name:CanCreateCustomView. Possible roles are CanAddKycCheck, CanAddKycDocument, ..............., CanUseAccountFirehoseAtAnyBank, CanUseCustomerFirehoseAtAnyBank}
```

in the grant role response above, the list of roles does not include `CanCreateCustomView`
Any help or feedback much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**CanCreateCustomView** is not a role, it is a permission in side the views.

Please join https://chat.openbankproject.com/  and ask question to the Open Bank Project teams... they can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

the solution here was 2 more api calls and an update in the scala properties

details

1. to grant the needed  `cancreatecustomview permission`

   need to call the [Grants  User access to view](https://apiexplorersandbox.openbankproject.com/?version=OBPv5.1.0&operation_id=OBPv4_0_0-grantUserAccessToView&currentTag=Account-Access&locale=en_GB#OBPv4_0_0-grantUserAccessToView)
   **Request**

   **url** like `/obp/v5.1.0/banks/BANK_ID/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/account-access/grant`
   **body** like

   {  "user_id":"userwithaccount-ID",  "view":{    "ManageCustomViews":"owner",    "is_system":true  }}

for this to work the userid must have an account,
that is the account table row has this userid AND the userid
must have been granted the "CanCreateSystemView" role

2. after you have successfully set the `ManageCustomViews` system view you need a second api call to update/refresh the [users permissions](https://apiexplorersandbox.openbankproject.com/?version=OBPv5.1.0&operation_id=OBPv3_1_0-refreshUser&currentTag=User&locale=en_GB#OBPv3_1_0-refreshUser)
   **Request**
   **url** like /obp/v5.1.0/users/USER_ID/refresh

at this point this user can create custom views
and you are past the `cancreatecustomview permission`
error above

3. in the case your custom view is a public view you need to update the scala codes `default.props` and set the property  `allow_public_views=true` it defaults to false.

with these steps I was able to get past the  `OBP-20022` and create custom views